# Fetch newest record of specific type

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am building an access database for storage of measurements and want to be able to retrieve the last measurement from all locations I measure using a query but I can't figure out how to do it. I tried with DISTINCT, INNER JOIN and Group by but I can't figure it out.

```
Id  Datum       Tijd    LuikNr      Value   
4   16-2-2015   1:00:00 01K0001     21  
7   31-1-2015   3:00:00 01K0002     2   
8   31-1-2015   5:25:00 04K0002     30  
12  19-2-2015   1:03:02 01K0001     1   
21  12-2-2015   9:00:00 01K0001     15
```

This is my table (Meetwaarden) layout. I want one record to return for each "LuikNr" value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does LuikNr = Location? Does Value = measurement? What exactly do you mean by the Last measurement? Last to me means Date/Time but I assumend Value to be a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want the highest datum AND tijd for each Luiknr.  You would do it with two max sub-selects. This would be the code:

```
Select * from Meetwaarden M1
Where M1.Datum = (select Max(M2.Datum) from Meetwaarden M2
                  Where M2.LuikNr = M1.LuikNr)
  and M1.Tijd = (select max(M3.tijd) from Meetwaarden M3
                 Where M3.Luiknr = M1.LuikNr
                   and M3.Datum = M1.Datum)
```

The subselect (with M2) searches through the table and finds the maximum datum for the LuikNr.  Then the M3 subselect gets the maximum time for that day.

Hope this works

Comment: It updated your code to include my own table name (Meetwaarden) and when i run it it returns about 15 records while there are only 4 different LuikNr's in my table so it should only return the one with the highest date and time from each LuikNr. Thanks anyway

Comment: @dannyvdz - updated my answer to include your table name and Tijd maximum for the datum

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to hit the table all that often. One simple query gives you everything you need to uniquely identify the rows you are looking for:

```
select  LuikNr, Max( Datum ) as Datum
from    Meetwaarden
group by LuikNr;
```

Now just use that in a CTE and join to it. You can read the entire row of Meetwaarden and the execution plan is much simpler.

```
with
MostRecent( LuikNr, Datum )as(
    select  LuikNr, Max( Datum ) as Datum
    from    Meetwaarden
    group by LuikNr
)
select  m.*
from    Meetwaarden m
join    MostRecent  mr
    on  mr.LuikNr   = m.LuikNr
    and mr.Datum    = m.Datum;
```

Comment: I'm intrigued because the max code I displayed above is similar to what we use in PeopleSoft SQRs and if we could cut out one of 3 accesses to the same table, that would be wonderful. In the OP's question, both the max datum (date) and the max tijd (time) have to be selected.  The code in your answer doesn't reflect the max time but only the max date.  How would you change that to reflect the max time for each max date?  Can you do it with single group by?  (btw, my first unedited answer had the same answer as you did - just max datum)

Comment: That could be done in the MostRecent cte by combining the date and times fields into a datetime value and selecting the max of that value. One hit and you have the max datetime. You may have to separate them back again, but calculation is orders of magnitude faster than a single table access.